# How to most efficiently find multiple duplicate values in Binary Search Tree

Tags: java, algorithm, binary-search-tree

How can I write an algorithm that finds all multiple duplicate values in Binary Search Tree when you are allowed to add duplicate values either on the left subtree or right subtree after applying balanced tree algorithm to an unbalanced tree?

Comment: What is a "multiple duplicate value"? How is your "Binary Search Tree" represented, and what form should the return-value take? What is the "balanced tree algorithm"?

Answer (score 0):

Normally in a tree search, you stop when you have found the desired element. In this case, you keep the recursion going when the values match. Instead of returning the node found, you return a count that is accumulated in the recursive calls.